# Adding speaker 1 and 2 in a titlepage (I think it's simple but I don't know how to do it)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, center

[image]

Hi everyone, how do I add two lines on the left and two on the right?
(name1 and name2 in \small, andspeaker in \footenotesize )

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{url,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{capitoli/bibliografia/bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} %pacchetto per scrivere come Matlab

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[]{} %pulisce il fancyhead
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} %sulle dispari la section
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %sulle pari il capitolo
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage} %numeri di pagina, a sinistra sulle dipari, a destra sulle pari

%\usepackage{pdfpages}

%queste due righe servono per non far apparire i numeri dei capitoli e delle sezioni nei fancyhead
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\parindent 0ex %serve per l'indentadure dei paragrafi

%paccheetto per i grafici
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %l'ho messo a caso per il grouplot
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} %l'ho messo a caso per il grouplot
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %ridondante ma per ora lo tengo
\usepackage{comment}



\usepackage{hyperref} %pacchetto Harvard che permette il collegamento da indice


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{0.2 cm}
        
        \Large
        \textbf{University}\\
        \vspace*{1 cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{titlepage/logo_2}
        
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        \large
        Department\\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \small
        faculty\\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \large
        thesis
        
        \vspace{1 cm}
        \large
        \textbf{title}
        
        \vspace{2cm}
        \footnotesize
        candidate:\\
        \normalsize
        \textbf{name}\\
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        
        
        
        \vfill
        
        


        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{0.2 cm}

\Large
\textbf{University}

\vspace*{1 cm}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{titlepage/logo_2}

\vspace{1cm}
\large
Department

\vspace{1cm}
\small
faculty

\vspace{1cm}
\large
thesis

\vspace{1 cm}
\large
\textbf{title}

\vspace{2cm}
\footnotesize
candidate:

\normalsize
\textbf{name}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
 \footnotesize 
 Speaker 1

 \small  
 Name 1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
 \footnotesize 
  Speaker 2

 \small
 Name 2
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]